# List not displaying in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Main Activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/ToolbarMain"
        tools:targetApi="honeycomb">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ToolbarMain">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main activity.java

```
package com.example.admin.ttabledemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupIViews();
        iniToolbar();
    }

    private void setupIViews(){
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarMain);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    }

    private void iniToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TIMETABLE APP");
    }
```

I am trying to build a time table app. List is not displaying. Just the titlebar.

Although in design listview is visible. please help.

Nothing is showing on the screen. I can't figure out what is wrong.
This is my first attempt to build an app. I am a complete beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setAdapter() like this way.

```
String data[] = new String[]{"Most Popular", "UpComing", "Top Rated"};

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        YourAdapterName cma = new YourAdapterName(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        listview .setAdapter(cma);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something to show. Try the following code:

```
    String items[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks. I reailsed the problem, I did'nt call the setUpListviews method() in my main class.